# how to make my ui in my shinyapp interactive

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, interactive

My interactive ui of the app only works in combination. I always have to change the select_Input of the "Info"-Field when I want to change the value of my dataset for category_1 or category_2. If I only want to replace the value of Category_1 or Category_2 without changing the Info_input the app chrashes. So I never can calculate the intresting value without changing the Info_input. But why?

```
library(shiny)

a <- c("E","D","E","E")
b <- c(10,20,10,10)
d <- c("aa","a","aa","b")
dd<- c(2,22,2, 54)
e <- c("house","car", "color","house")
f <- c(1,3,4,1)


df <- data.frame(cat1 =a, cat1_value=b, info=d, info_value= dd, cat2=e, cat2_value=f)


ref <- c("aaa","aa","a", "bb","b", "c")
val <- c(0.4, 2, 22, 43, 54, 0.6)

df_reference <- data.frame(reference =ref, value=val)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Test Explorer"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Cat2", "Category_2",
                  c("",unique(df$cat2))),
      
      uiOutput("ui2"),
      selectInput("Cat1", "Category_1",
                        c("",unique(df$cat1))),
      
      uiOutput("ui3"),
    
      selectInput("Info", "Infoo",
                        c("",unique(df$info))),
      
      column(3, actionButton("re", label = "replace"),
                         
                         
           actionButton("calc", label = "calculate"))),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("result")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  

  
  output$ui2 <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$Cat2)) # 
      return()
    
    switch(input$Cat2,
           "house" = numericInput("tt", "tt in %",
                                          100),
           "car" = numericInput("tt", "tt in %",
                                     40),
           "color" = numericInput("tt", "tt in %",
                                         60)
           
    )
  })
  
  
  
  
  output$ui3 <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$Cat1)) #
      return()
    
    
    switch(input$Cat1,
           
           "E" = numericInput("bb", "bbin %",
                                   10),
           "D" = numericInput("bb", "bb in %",
                                        20)
           
           
    )
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$re, ({            ## mit reactive und reactiveValues lösen ## Warum so dumm?
    
    
    df$cat2_value[df$cat2 == input$Cat2] <<- input$tt/100   
    df$cat1_value[df$cat1 == input$Cat1] <<- input$bb/100
    df$info <<- input$Info
    df$info_value <<- df_reference[df_reference$reference %in% input$Info,]$value 
  
  
  
  
}))
  
  observeEvent(input$calc, ({
    
    
    output$result <- renderText({
      
      sum(df$info_value * df$cat1_value * df$cat2_value)
      
    })
    
  }))
  
}
    

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that if you don't choose anything for `info`,`input$info` is `NULL` what breaks the assignment in the df. What exactly do you want to do with your app? The calculation/reactivity seems a bit odd for me, directly modifying the global data.frame with the original data. I would use extra variables (maybe reactives or reactive values) for this.

Comment: but then it should also work with isolate(input$info) but it doesnt. yes i can use reactives but this also does not solve the problem.

Comment: No, `isolate(input$info)` just prevents reactivity to depend on `input$info` which doesn't matter because it's in an `observeEvent` which depends on another input. `input$info` is still `NULL`

Comment: I have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

If I do it like this - now the app doesnt react on Category_2. Is there a full working solution?

```
library(shiny)

a <- c("E","D","E","E")
b <- c(10,20,10,10)
d <- c("aa","a","aa","b")
dd<- c(2,22,2, 54)
e <- c("house","car", "color","house")
f <- c(1,3,4,1)


df <- data.frame(cat1 =a, cat1_value=b, info=d, info_value= dd, cat2=e, cat2_value=f)


ref <- c("aaa","aa","a", "bb","b", "c")
val <- c(0.4, 2, 22, 43, 54, 0.6)

df_reference <- data.frame(reference =ref, value=val)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Test Explorer"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Cat2", "Category_2",
                  c("",unique(df$cat2))),
      
      uiOutput("ui2"),
      selectInput("Cat1", "Category_1",
                        c("",unique(df$cat1))),
      
      uiOutput("ui3"),
    
      selectInput("Info", "Infoo",
                        c("",unique(df$info))),
      
      column(3, actionButton("re", label = "replace"),
                         
                         
           actionButton("calc", label = "calculate"))),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("result")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  

  
  output$ui2 <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$Cat2)) # 
      return()
    
    switch(input$Cat2,
           "house" = numericInput("tt", "tt in %",
                                          100),
           "car" = numericInput("tt", "tt in %",
                                     40),
           "color" = numericInput("tt", "tt in %",
                                         60)
           
    )
  })
  
  
  
  
  output$ui3 <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$Cat1)) #
      return()
    
    
    switch(input$Cat1,
           
           "E" = numericInput("bb", "bbin %",
                                   10),
           "D" = numericInput("bb", "bb in %",
                                        20)
           
           
    )
  })
  

  
  
  observeEvent(input$re, ({           
    
   # a <<- ifelse(is.null(input$Info),df$info, input$Info)
    
    df$cat2_value[df$cat2 == input$Cat2] <<- input$tt/100   
    df$cat1_value[df$cat1 == input$Cat1] <<- input$bb/100
   # df$info_value <<- df_reference[df_reference$reference %in% a,]$value

  
}))
  
  observeEvent(c(input$re,input$Info), ({
     req(input$Info) 
    df$info_value <<- df_reference[df_reference$reference %in% input$Info,]$value
    
  })  
  )  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$calc, ({
    
    output$result <- renderText({
      

      sum(df$info_value * df$cat1_value * df$info_value)
      
    })
    
  }))
  
}
    

shinyApp(ui, server)
```